# First access to static arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a static ArrayList:

```
    public class Global {
    public static ArrayList<Player> Round;
}
```

As I understand it, one does not instantiate static arrays, so my first access to the ArrayList is:

```
    Player lPlayer = new Player(name,level);
    Global.Round.add(lPlayer);
```

and it crashes the app. Iam fairly confident that lPlayer is properly formed. This line is called when a new player is added so I never know if this is the first time I invoke the .add, but it shouldn't matter, right?

The error is "InvocationTargetException.(Throwable) line: 50".

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you initialize Round in Global?

Comment: If you look a bit better, the actual error is probably a `NullPointerException`, caused by *not* initializing the static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying:

> one does not instantiate static arrays,

*Where did you find it?*

you need to instantiate an instance field whither it is `static` or `non-static`. Only difference among them is that: `static` fields are associated with the `class`, rather than with any `object`. Every instance of the `class` shares a `class` variable, which is in one *fixed location in memory*.

You haven't initialized  the `ArrayList<Player> Round`. So create it:

```
public static ArrayList<Player> Round = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I probably dreamt it. It never made sense to me, so I'm glad to hear I was wrong. I put a `public static ArrayList<Player> Round = new ArrayList();` in the Global class def and I gt a warning _ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized_. Is this okay?

Comment: @ddk, Generic Collection class (such as `ArrayList` here) type should have parametrized with the class type we want to have the collection to contain the elements of. So when create it we write `new ArrayList<Player>()` which is appropriate. But from java 7, only a diamond operator: `<>` is sufficient that is `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: @ddk, as a new user, welcome to stack overflow. please check the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for hot to use this site. Thank you.

Comment: Sage, thanks for the welcome. Am I using the site incorrectly?

Comment: @ddk, no no i didn't mean that. I am saying, there are other answers including mine. Read them. You should accept the answer by clicking the tick mark, which satisfies your question the most. The choice of the answer is completely yours :)

Comment: Ah, so I get my answer _but_ I get to hurt someone's feelings, too ;

Answer (score 3):

Read the rest of the exception stack trace, and you'll probably find that the cause of your exception is a NullPointerException.

An ArrayList doesn't exist until you have instantiated it, just like any object. Whether it's static or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: Also, big warning here: this code is _not_ thread safe! You're accessing a non-thread-safe structure (`ArrayList`) without synchronization. If another thread comes along and reads or writes that `Global.Round` list, things can break in subtle, hard-to-debug ways.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize Round object like following. Otherwise you get NUllPointerException

```
public class Global {
    public static ArrayList<Player> Round = new ArrayList<>();
}
```